# Modal Jquery/ Materialize não funcionando no index.php

Tags: php, jquery, modal, materialize

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um modal de aceitação para termos de cookie. Consegui resolver através do php o armazenamento de cache. Porém, não consegui visualizar o porque do modal não aparecer no layout quando o usuário ainda não tem o cache armazenado do site.

Estou utilizando o Materialize para criar o modal.

Código Html:

```
<div id="modalPropaganda" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<h4>Modal Header</h4>
<p>Com o objetivo de fornecer um serviço mais personalizado e ágil, armazenamos informações sobre como você usa este site. Esse processo é realizado por meio de pequenos arquivos de textos chamados cookies. Eles contêm pequenas quantidades de informação e são baixados para o seu computador ou outro dispositivo por um servidor deste site. O seu navegador, em seguida, envia esses cookies de volta a cada nova visita. Desta forma, podemos reconhecer e lembrar de suas preferências. Você pode encontrar informações mais detalhadas sobre cookies e como funcionam <a href="/termo-de-cookie/">em nossa página.</a></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Confirmar e Fechar</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Código Php para declaração e expiração de cookie:

```
<?php

$cookieExistente = (isset($_COOKIE['modal']));

if(!$cookieExistente){
setcookie('modal', 'ok', strtotime('+7 days'));
}

?>
```

Código php e jquery para caso o usuário ainda não tenha o cache, exibir o modal para ele:

```
<?php if(!$cookieExistente) : ?>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modalCookie").modal('show');
    });
    </script>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

OBS: Ainda não tenho o css.
Utilizei o "Compiled and minified JavaScript" do Materialize para puxar a biblioteca do Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#modalCookie').modal().modal('open');
```

Primeiro você inicia o plugin e depois dispara o método `open` que abre a modal.

> Atente-se para o `id` da modal. No jQuery você está usando um `id`
>   diferente da modal.

Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#modalCookie').modal().modal('open'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div id="modalCookie" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<h4>Modal Header</h4>
<p>Com o objetivo de fornecer um serviço mais personalizado e ágil, armazenamos informações sobre como você usa este site. Esse processo é realizado por meio de pequenos arquivos de textos chamados cookies. Eles contêm pequenas quantidades de informação e são baixados para o seu computador ou outro dispositivo por um servidor deste site. O seu navegador, em seguida, envia esses cookies de volta a cada nova visita. Desta forma, podemos reconhecer e lembrar de suas preferências. Você pode encontrar informações mais detalhadas sobre cookies e como funcionam <a href="/termo-de-cookie/">em nossa página.</a></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Confirmar e Fechar</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ele está retornando o erro igual a foto em anexo na resposta minha. Será que apenas com css consigo organizar e resolver?

Comment: Qual erro? Não use o campo de respostas para acrescentar detalhes à pergunta. Use o link "editar".

Comment: Para ver o erro http://www.siteesquadros.kinghost.net/ Ele está no menu.

Comment: Descreva o erro. Não consegui ver nada de errado.

Comment: Ele está deixando abaixo do header uma faixa em tom avermelhado. O print: https://imgur.com/f6tXNZo

Comment: Tem um print de como era pra ser?

Comment: Seria assim a ideia: https://imgur.com/RRgCPEp

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102333/discussion-between-sam-and-renan-ranzani).